# Easiest way to extract the coefficient of a polynomial

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

For a term in a polynomial, say

```
387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364
```

what is the most efficient way to extract the coefficient of this term, i.e. `387`?

Comment: Put all variables equal to 1?

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
poly = 387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364;

vars = Variables[poly];
exps = Exponent[poly, vars];

Coefficient[poly, Times @@ (vars^exps)]
```

> ```
> 387
> ```

or

```
Cancel[poly/(Times @@ (vars^exps))]
```

> ```
> 387
> ```

p.s. In general, you'd want to hit your polynomial with [`MonomialList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MonomialList.html) if it's not a proper monomial.

And just for fun, here's an overly complicated solution

```
poly = 387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364;
vars = Variables[poly];

Times @@ ((# D[Log[poly], #]) + 1 & /@ vars) * 
  Fold[Integrate[#1, {#2, 0, 1}] &, poly, vars]
```

> ```
> 387
> ```

Answer (score 6):

**Example:**

```
(*Example 1*)   
Select[387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364, IntegerQ]

(*Example 2*)
Select[x^2 y^6, IntegerQ]
```

**Output:**

```
(*Output 1*)
387

(*Output 2*)
1
```

**Reference:**

[Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html?q=Select)
[IntegerQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerQ.html?q=IntegerQ)

Comment: This is so beautiful, thank you.

Comment: I am sure there are other solutions but this should do it. Glad it helped

Comment: It works only if the head is `Times`, for example `Select[x^2, IntegerQ]` returns `2`.

Comment: Multiplying by `Unique[]` adds
 very little overhead: `Select[x^2 Unique[], IntegerQ]` or in general `Select[monomial * Unique[], NumericQ]`.  `Select` is the fastest way I've found.

Answer (score 6):

```
lookMaNoXYZ = 1 & @@@ # &;

lookMaNoXYZ[ x^2 y^6 ]
```

> 1

```
lookMaNoXYZ[10 x^2  Pi y^6 / 4]
```

> (5 π)/2

```
lookMaNoXYZ[x^2 55. y^6]
```

> 55.

Comment: ... i am also puzzled how/why this works.

Comment: So it replaces all the powers with 1's... obviously

Comment: Try `lookMaNoXYZ[Sqrt[2/3] x^5 y^7]`.

Comment: To extend the [comment by J. M.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115006/easiest-way-to-extract-the-coefficient-of-a-polynomial/115012#comment312008_115012): `lookMaNoXYZ` fails whenever parts of the coefficient are not `AtomQ`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[cF]
cF = # /. Thread[Variables[#] -> 1] &;

cF[x^2 y^6 ]
```

> 1

```
cF [367 a1^4 a2^3 x^3   y^7 z^100 w^364 ]
```

> 367

Answer (score 4):

```
poly = 387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364;

CoefficientRules[poly][[1, 2]]
```

> 387

Comment: `CoefficientRules[poly]` is`{{4, 3, 364, 3, 7, 100} -> 387}`.  Also, `FromCoefficientRules[%, Variables[poly]] == poly` is `True`

Answer (score 2):

Using some undocumented functionality:

```
poly = 387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364;
GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[poly, Variables[poly]][[1, 1, 2]]
   387

poly2 = Sqrt[2/3] x^5 y^7;
GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[poly2, Variables[poly2]][[1, 1, 2]]
   Sqrt[2/3]

GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[x^3 y^2, {x, y}][[1, 1, 2]]
   1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`FactorTermsList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorTermsList):

```
First @ FactorTermsList[387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364]
```

> 387

Answer (score 1):

for your particular example, this is quite simple:

```
FirstCase[387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364, _Integer]
(* 387 *)
```

this case works even with integer being not in the first position:

```
FirstCase[a1^4 a2^3 x^3 387 y^7 z^100 w^364, _Integer]
(* 387 *)
```

Also, as @MichaelE2 suggested **perhaps the shortest answer**:

```
First[a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 387 z^100 w^364]
(* 387 *)
```

Comment: For this particular example, `First[387 a1^4 a2^3 x^3 y^7 z^100 w^364]` is even simpler. :)

Comment: Agreed @MichaelE2