# How to extract all the coefficients of a homogeneous polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, coefficients

Suppose `p` is a homogeneous polynomial in four variables, say

```
p = x^10 y^10 z^5 w^5 + 3 a x^10 w^20;
```

`p` is a homogeneous polynomial of degree 30, where `a` is a free parameter. I want to extract the coefficients of monomials, which is just

```
{1, 3 a}
```

There is a function in *Mathematica*, `CoefficentList`; however, it is very very inefficient, if I do the following evaluation

```
Flatten[CoefficientList[p, {x, y, z, w}]]
```

It contains 15246 coefficients and 15244 coefficients out of 15246 are 0. So is there any more efficient and more quick way to extract the coefficients of a homogeneous polynomial of high degree in four variables?

Comment: Maybe `In[9]:= Apply[List, p] /. Thread[{x, y, z, w} -> 1]

Out[9]= {3 a, 1}`

Comment: Does [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115006) look familiar to you?

Answer (score 14):

Using an *undocumented* function:

```
GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[x^10 y^10 z^5 w^5 + 3 a x^10 w^20,
                                   {x, y, z, w}][[1, All, -1]]
   {1, 3 a}
```

---

Here's a *documented* solution:

```
CoefficientRules[x^10 y^10 z^5 w^5 + 3 a x^10 w^20, {x, y, z, w}]
   {{10, 10, 5, 5} -> 1, {10, 0, 0, 20} -> 3 a}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know where I could find more details about this DistributedTermsList?

Comment: As I had emphasized in my answer, it's *undocumented*. This has been used before on this site and in MathGroup (you can search for those examples yourself), but there is no documentation for it.

Comment: @Wenzhe - You can at least see the available options using ``Options[GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList]``.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you!